# Nuxt Import library to use within extendRoutes

Tags: nuxt.js

When I try to import a library to use within `extendRoutes` in `nuxt.config.js`, I end up getting a runtime error:

> `_myModule is not defined`

Is this not supported? Are there any workarounds?

To reproduce:

```js
// nuxt.config.js
import myModule from "./scripts/myModule";

router: {
   extendRoutes: function(routes) {
       routes.push({
          path: "/from",
          redirect(from) {
            myModule(from);
            return "/to";
          }
       });
   }
}
```

When I look inside the `.nuxt/router.js`, I see that no module was imported at the top, and the resulting code shows:

```js
 path: "/from",
    redirect: function(from) {
          (0, _myModule.default)(from);
          return '/to';
        }
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue when using a library in stringifyQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to fix this, but found a workaround:

I've added a `middleware/extendRouter.ts` script, and added this to `nuxt.config.js`:

```
router: {
    middleware: ['extendRouter'],
}
```

The middleware doesn't have the same issue with importing scripts